# I need to save only z values for 3D PointField in Geodjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I have a location database for some objects using PointField with 3 dimensions. But it turns out some users only have the z coordinate (elevation) for the objects and not x and y. PointField doesn't let me define a point with only z coordinate.

I really don't want to break up the PointField into two fields as it is very convenient for me this way. It would be great if there is a work-around that I could use.

```
In []: Point(x=1,y=2,z=3).z
Out[]: 3.0
In []: Point(z=3).z
Out[]:
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very strange for a user to have an elevation value and not the Lon/Lat of his position, but as a workaround, why don't you use a fixed value for X, Y, Z if the user does not provide those?

```
DEFAULT_X = 0
DEFAULT_Y = 0
DEFAULT_Z = 0

def create_point(x=None, y=None, z=None):
    return Point(
        x=x if x else DEFAULT_X,
        y=y if y else DEFAULT_Y,
        z=z if z else DEFAULT_Z
    )
```

Keep in mind that your default values should be something that cannot randomly occur in your dataset, else you may mix up your data.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. The only problem would be that I'd have to check against the default x, y, z values when plotting a map, which would mean some refactoring in the code.